# Checking for data before sending it

Tags: php

How to validate the fields on my site before they get sent to the other site where they are processed? Right now it still sends the user to the other site.

Right now the site that processes the data shows their custom error message on their site. It is an inconvenience. This is the exact order how the code goes.

The PHP code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
      {
             $name = $_POST['name'];
             $email = $_POST['email'];
             $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
             $error_message = "";

            if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone) )
              {
               $error_message = "<span class='error-message'>Fill all fields</span>";   
              }
      }
                      ?>
```

The HTML code that comes after

```
<form method="post" action="Some other site that processes everything" class="big_form" >
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.example.com" />

    <!-- Some more form fields that are not necessary for this example-->

</form>
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: For form validation as you describe, the easiest way would be with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server side code, so if you're wanting to stay on the same page and do a POST with a response you'll need Javascript one way or the other. Better yet, you should validate your form with Javascript before sending it to PHP. You can watch the onsubmit event from the form.

```
<form onsubmit="validate();">

function validate() {
   //Check to see if everything is set otherwise error
}
```

Also http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: I have zero knowledge in Javascript. Can you be so kind and provide the code?

Comment: It's hard to write code to validate your form without knowing exactly what you want. If you're only looking to see if an input is filled out, you might want to check out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: Thanks, this will do for now. Yes I'm looking to see if the input is filled out or no.

Comment: @TacoCat Just as a note, that `required` attribute does not work in Safari and only in later versions of IE, so it's probably a good idea to leave your PHP validation in just for those who slip through.  Of course the javascript approach should also help